# MFC SIGNAL AND WRITE OPERATION

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture

Is there any MFC(memory function completed) signal generated after write operation is completed?
I am reading a book on computer organisation by Carl Hamacher, in this book it is written that a MFC signal is generated after read operation completes, but it is not clear in the text(pg no. 293)  whether it is generated in case of completion of write operation also.

Comment: What cpu-architecture is that book talking about?  That's not a general thing in the internals of every CPU.  For example, many pipelined CPUs have a store buffer that pipelines stores, and commits them to L1D at some point after the store instruction retires (i.e. they're known to be non-speculative.)

Comment: It's talking about general memory system i.e how it works.

Comment: Well, memory controllers need to know when a write completes, and any higher levels of the memory hierarchy need to know when the next level down has accepted the data.  What the CPU designers call the relevant signal probably varies.  From the CPU pipeline perspective, writes are fire-and-forget / asynchronous, very different from loads where execution has to wait for the data.  The pipeline doesn't have to wait for writes to complete (except when there's a memory fence instruction in the pipeline).

Comment: In general, a device conforms to some electrical timings (take a datasheet of any memory device). Conforming to such timing is enough for considering the write completed. For example, if after the strobe of a write signal the next 2 cycles are used to drive the data lines, then, after two cycles the write is complete. There is no need for an explicit signal. This is also true for reads. Internally the accepting device may generate a signal (with a counter) to trigger some logic. So, we can make an MFC out of thin air just like we can divide an expression into multiple partial results.

Answer (score 0):

Memory function complete or MFC is just a signal that tells the cpu that the current operation involving the memory is complete and by that definition it is obvious that MFC signal will be generated in case of write operation also as in the case of read operation.